# Problemas para plotar gráfico com função chartSeries do pacote quantmod a partir de um data.frame em R

Tags: r

Estou com problemas para plotar um gráfico de candlesticks a partir de um arquivo `data.frame`.

Exemplo do código

```
# Pacotes necessários ---------------------------------------------- 
library(BatchGetSymbols)
library(quantmod)
# Inputs necessários ------------------------------------------------------
#data inicial
first.date <- as.Date("2018-01-01")
#data final
last.date <- Sys.Date()
#frequencia das observações
freq.data <- 'daily'
# Ativos a serem baixados
tickers <- c("^BVSP")
# Importando ativos -------------------------------------------------------
ibov <- BatchGetSymbols(tickers = tickers, 
                      first.date = first.date,
                      last.date = last.date, 
                      freq.data = freq.data,
                      cache.folder = file.path(tempdir(), 
                                               'BGS_Cache') ) 
ibov<-as.data.frame(ibov)
```

Com esse código são importados os dados para um exemplo. O que eu gostaria de aprender seria como plotar esses dados usando a função.

```
chartSeries
```

A partir do data.frame `ibov`, tentei fazer da seguinte maneira:

```
ibov <- xts(ibov, order.by = ibov$df.tickers.ref.date)
chartSeries(ibov)
```

Porém está aparecendo o erro:

```
Error in (function (cl, name, valueClass)  : 
assignment of an object of class “character” is not valid for @‘yrange’ in 
an object of class “chob”; is(value, "numeric") is not TRUE
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Funcionou assim para mim:

```
library(tidyverse)
ibov <- xts(
  ibov$df.tickers %>% select(-ref.date, -ticker), 
  order.by = ibov$df.tickers$ref.date
  )
chartSeries(ibov)
```

Também excluí essa linha do seu código: `ibov<-as.data.frame(ibov)`.

A ideia é que na hora de converter para um objeto do tipo `xts` não pode existir nenhuma variável do tipo `character` no data.frame.

Uma outra solução, dado que você já está com o data.frame transformado seria fazer assim:

```
ibov <- xts(ibov %>% select_if(is.numeric), order.by = ibov$df.tickers.ref.date)
chartSeries(ibov)
```

Comment: isso não está claro na sua pergunta, mas enfim.. o que vc precisa é tirar todas as colunas que não são numéricas do data.frame. vou atualizar com uma possível solucao

Comment: Muito obrigado Daniel, essa outra solução resolveu perfeitamente o problema, muito obrigado mesmo