# Como plotar gráfico do dólar usando o comando chartseries

Tags: r

```
dolar <- getSymbols("CL=F", src = "yahoo") # pega os dados do yahoo finance

chartSeries(dolar, type = "line", theme = "white", TA=NULL)  # monta o gráfico
```

Dá o erro

```
Error in try.xts(x, error = "chartSeries requires an xtsible object") : 
  chartSeries requires an xtsible object
```

Comment: Talvez relacionada ou dup de [Problemas para plotar gráfico com função chartSeries do pacote quantmod a partir de um data.frame em R](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/349921/problemas-para-plotar-gr%c3%a1fico-com-fun%c3%a7%c3%a3o-chartseries-do-pacote-quantmod-a-partir)

Comment: A função `getSymbols` está a ter como saída `"CL=F"`, e não a série.

Comment: Muito obrigado Rui.